# Flutter/Dart Reload widget and send new data

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to have a text field in a widget where you can search for something. If the string changes, the widget should be reloaded and the new data sent.
I've read many things about a callback function, unfortunately I don't quite understand it at flutter.
Below you will find the sample code:
Thanks for your help

```
class _HomepageState extends State<Homepage> {
  String data;
  String day;
  ...
  TextField(
   onChanged: (str){
     setState(() {
      data = str;
     });
    },
   ),
   ...
 Nextpage(data: data, day: day,)
 ...
}
class Nextpage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String data;
  final String day;
  Nextpage({this.data, this.day});
...
print(widget.data);
...
}
```

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything inherently wrong with the code you shared. Could you please clarify what you are trying to achieve and possibly share more of your code?

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example where you have a `TextField`, and as its input changes, the text is shown on a different `Text` widget (you can copy it and paste it to [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev) to see how it works in action).

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  String myText = '';

  TextField buildTextField() {
    return TextField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: 'Enter Text',
      ),
      onChanged: (changedText) => updateText(changedText),
      onEditingComplete: () => print("complete"),
    );
  }

  void updateText(newText) {
    setState(() {
      myText = newText;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: "Example",
        theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.deepPurple),
        home: Scaffold(
          body: Container(
            child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: [
                  buildTextField(),
                  Text(myText),
                ]),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

The callback is this part of the code:

```
onChanged: (changedText) => updateText(changedText)
```

and the callback function is `updateText`.

This is another example of a callback where the `print` function (the callback function) is called after the editing is complete.

```
onEditingComplete: () => print("complete")
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks OsaXma for your quick reply. Unfortunately, it didn't completely solve my problem, so I've tried something like that.
But I want to have a text field in a class, and whenever this changes, the current data should be sent to a new class that is then updated.